# How to change fontsize of xticklabel and yticklabel equal to the fontsize of caption?

Tags: pgfplots, graphics, fontsize

I am using two column format to write a paper. I have arranged two figures side by side in one column. But their xticklabels and yticklabels are too small I want change their fontsize. Can I do that using Latex? My figures already have xticklabels and yticklabels. Can I change it using Latex. I read about tickz But I don't complemetly understand what will be better choice.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn, 10pt]{article}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{figure}[H]
\sidesubfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.49\columnwidth,height=4cm}]
{Fig1.PNG}}
\sidesubfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.49\columnwidth,height=4cm}] 
{Fig2.PNG}}
\end{figure}
```

I tried to add these packages but it doesn't have any effect on ticklabels.

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{every x tick label/.append style={font=\scriptsize}}
```

Comment: Kindly add your preamble part, because it may reflect the document part. @jerry

Comment: I have updated my question

Comment: We haven't your images nor know, how they are drawn. Since you import them as `png` files, the size of fonts is scaled with images. You should drawn your images in approximately size as they will appear in document.

Comment: Yes my image is in png and png image has ticklables. So does it mean that I can't change it from Latex? In two column paper I have seen two side by side images where ticklables are quite visible. Is there any other option? Or should I increase my image size in the Latex. Like I fix figure at the top and bottom of the page

Comment: By the way your code is unableto run  @jerry

Comment: I have fixed the error

Comment: That depends on **how** you have created your images. Because you didn't add an image with your current result we cannot even *guess* how they were created. Because your provided code shows the `pgfplots` package we can guess that you created them with this, exported the plots somehow and then incorporate them with `\includegraphics`.

Comment: So when you simply don't export the plots but use them directly your question can easily be solved. Even if you need to export them because they need a lot of computation time this can be done when you use TikZ's [tag:tikz-external] library.

Comment: Actually I am using a simple subfigure  package . I have a simple PNG image that already has values along x-axis and y-axis. I want to know that can I increase font size of ticklabels by Latex. If yes then how.  I am not using pgfplots package . That I tried at the end just yo see whether it works for getting the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot adjust the fontsize of the labels in the png, because the png is a pixel based format, so they are no longer text, just pixels.

For vector based formats it is sometimes possible to adjust the font, for example with psfrac.

Alternative: recreate the plot in latex, then the font size will be right

```
\documentclass[twocolumn, 10pt]{article}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{caption}
%\usepackage{subfig}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{
    every tick label/.append style={font=\scriptsize}
}

\begin{document}


\begin{figure}[htbp]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
        width=.49\columnwidth,
    extra x ticks={-2,2},
    extra y ticks={-2,2},
    extra tick style={grid=major}]
    \addplot {x};
    \draw (axis cs:0,0) circle[radius=2];
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
        width=.49\columnwidth,
    extra x ticks={-2,2},
    extra y ticks={-2,2},
    extra tick style={grid=major}]
    \addplot {x};
    \draw (axis cs:0,0) circle[radius=2];
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```